# Loading modules JS

Tags: javascript

I'm having a synchronization and loading issues with some JS modules when the program starts. This error only shows up once at the beginning and then everything works, so it is an obvious sync problem.

The code:

```
//pyramid of doom
function initGame(){
  initWorld(function(){
    initPlayer(function(){
      initBots(function(){
        console.log("Game Loaded!");
        update();
      })
    })
  });
}
function initWorld(callback){
  world.init(worldParams);
  callback&&callback();
}
function initPlayer(callback){
  player.init(scene,playerParams,world.getPhysicModel());
  callback&&callback();
}
function initBots(callback){
  bots.init(scene,botsParams,world.getPhysicModel());
  callback&&callback();
}
function update() {
  world.update(1/60);
  player.update();
  bots.update();
}
initGame();
```

The following is the error I'm getting.

```
Bots.js:112 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mixer' of undefined
    at Bots.update (Bots.js:112)
    at update (Final.html:160)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I synchronize the execution of the init functions?

(What I think that is going on is that the execution of initBots doesn't reach it end before the udpdate function starts to run.)

You can find the Bots.js module in my repository at ( [1](https://github.com/tul1/walkingCharactersThreeJS/blob/master/sandbox/Final/js2/Bots.js)  )

Comment: Well it would be nice to know what the error is.

Comment: There is no question in this question. In addition to that, it would probably be useful to see what `Bots.js` does.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's going wrong. You reference `self._bots[i].mixer` in two places in `Bots.update`. One of those two places is where the exception is being thrown because `self._bots[i]` is evaluating to `undefined`. Find that, then either figure out how to avoid it, or ensure the value is defined before accessing a property.

Answer (score 2):

In `bots.init` you execute `new THREE.ColladaLoader().load` which looks to be asynchronous.

In its callback, you fill your `_bots` array (`self._bots[modelLoaded] = bot;`).

However, you execute `bots.init()` and do not wait for these asynchronous calls to complete before executing the `initBots` function callback. In the case of `initGame` execution, this callback executes `update()`, which in turn executes `bots.update()`, which tries to access `this._bots[i].mixer` with `i` index up to `this._botsParams.length`, i.e. a pre-defined value that does not account for how many items have been actually filled in `_bots` array.

Hence your error message: the array has no items yet at some indices, and trying to read a property on `undefined` throws an error.

Conclusion: common asynchronous issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be passing the callbacks into the init functions. Guessing from a brief look at your bots code, they are not expecting to receive callbacks so you might be in for a rebuild.

You can't tell from the outside of an async function if it is done yet!

Equivalent to what you are doing:

```js
let result = undefined

function takeTime () {
  setTimeout(function() {
    result = 'hello!'
  }, 100)
}

function callback () {
  console.log(result)
}

function run (callback) {
  takeTime()
  callback && callback()
}

run(callback) // undefined! takeTime has not finished yet
```

What you need to be doing:

```js
let result = undefined

function takeTime (callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    result = 'hello!'
    callback()
  }, 100)
}

function callback () {
  console.log(result)
}

function run (callback) {
  callback && takeTime(callback)
}

run(callback) // 'hello!', the callback was only called once the takeTime function completed
```